# inner product and conjuction

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question regarding a general inner product space.

V is a inner product space.

() is the inner product.

can I say that :

$\overline{(a,b)}$ $\overline{(c,d)}$ = $\overline{(a,b)(c,d)}$

I am asking that because I know that over the complex It is true.

but the field not always will be the complex so...

can I say it ?

Is it true ?

if not how can I proof that ?

Comment: I think I didn't understand. How you'll define the conjugate outside the field of Complex Numbers?

Answer (score 1):

How do you define the conjugate of a number if you are not in a complex or real field? Or the inner product?

But over the reals or complex numbers, the following equality is of course true, as (a,b) are just numbers.